# Why contentItem.value is null- Lightswitch

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I want to hide a control based upon a property. So I handle the PostRender event like this
[image: Lightswitch Printscreen]

But I'm getting contentItem.value = null

How can I access the original object, so I can check the property that will hide the control?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried manually passing the value from what I presume is a browse screen to a view screen? you could then complete this with the screen created event....

Comment: one more thing ill ask before I post an answer, have you manually added the tables in on the window on the left hand side or clicked on the foreign links between the tables? or are the 2 tables not related via a foreign key, but contain a common field?

Comment: @RonaldPaguay Did my proposed answer help to provide a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information you've provided it appears that, at the point of rendering the control, its value hasn't updated yet.

As this isn't an unusual situation, the normal approach to handle this is to use LightSwitch's dataBind function which would be used as follows in your example: -

```
myapp.ConfirmarRecepcion.GUIAItem_pagadoEntrega_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {
    // Write code here.
    contentItem.dataBind("value", function (value) {
        if (value.Documento.id != 1) {
            $(GUIAItem_pagadoEntrega).addClass(oculto);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, if value.Documento refers to a related entity, you should use the following approach to ensure its value has been retrieved: -

```
myapp.ConfirmarRecepcion.GUIAItem_pagadoEntrega_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {
    // Write code here.
    contentItem.dataBind("value", function (value) {
        if (value) {
            value.getDocumento().then(function (documento) {
                if (documento && documento.id != 1) {
                    $(GUIAItem_pagadoEntrega).addClass(oculto);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```